# Additional package installed in my PythonAnywhere account is not found by app

Tags: pythonanywhere

I am trying to deploy my first Dash app to PythonAnywhere.  The app uses the dash_bootstrap_components package which is not part of the 'haggis' image used by my account.  I followed the instructions for installing the package and the bash console confirmed that it had successfully installed it.

[Copy of bash console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgzSk.png)

After installing the package I reloaded my app on the Web Tab in PythonAnywhere, but when I try to open my URL I get an error and the error log shows an ImportError.

[copy of error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVMsX.png)

Are there additional steps to follow in order to have my app "see" the additional package?

Answer (score 1):

looks like you've installed you're module in a different Python environment than the one your web app is running in. I'd recommend using virtual environments. They have a good help page - https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Virtualenvs/